# Update a date field when Title field is changed from blank in SharePoint 2010

Tags: date-time

I have a list where items are created with control numbers at project kickoff. I need to have a date field update when the column "Title" is first changed from blank to text. This field should never change. Can I do that with html code or out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this really is to write some custom code, OOTB features like calculated columns can't do [Today] or [Me] outputs :|

So you would need to add some custom JavaScript to the New and Edit form pages via a script link web part which evaluates the Title/Name field on focus lost (onBlur) and auto populates the Date Field if necessary. This code could also work disable the Name/Title text box to provide a read only type of behaviour when your conditions are met.